# ANDROID-compile error (no JVM initialized)

Tags: android

I am getting the following error while building the project using "ant debug".
Here is small the snap shot:

> -dex:
>        [echo] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\ELOQUENCE\b
>   in\classes.dex...
>       [apply] Could not create the Java virtual machine.
>       [apply] Error occurred during initialization of VM
>       [apply] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>   BUILD FAILED
>   H:\USE\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\ant_rules_r3.xml:361: The following error o
>   ccurred while executing this line:
>   H:\USE\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\ant_rules_r3.xml:174: apply returned: 1

please tell me what can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1036

Answer (score 10):

try to decrease setting for max heap space setting in file

```
android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\dx.bat
```

to smaller value. I had to change it to 512M instead of 1024M.

```
set defaultMx=-Xmx512M
```

Comment: updated path for dx.bat is : `android-sdk-windows\build-tools\x.x.x\dx.bat`  where x.x.x is targated version